# Difference between --noproxy and --no-proxy CURL?

Tags: curl, http-proxy

I can't find any documentation on it, or maybe it's just a weird behavior...

I have a curl command like this (simplified) that it is executed on a server behind a proxy, and I don't want to use the proxy for a specific route :

`curl toto:1337/api` -> doesn't work because of the proxy

`curl toto:1337/api --no-proxy toto:1337/api` -> works fine...

`curl toto:1337/api --noproxy toto:1337/api` -> doesn't work (hits the proxy)

`curl toto:1337/api --noproxy toto` -> works fine...

Anyone can explain the difference or link to some docs for `--no-proxy` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on github : https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/3906

It has been corrected so that it generates an error on non-boolean options (`--no` in `--no-proxy` was in fact `--proxy` with a boolean `false`).

> Yes, because --no-proxy will act exactly like --proxy. The --no-
>   prefix only has a meaning for boolean command line options.